Xcode Playgrounds - code does not display after git branches changed (from "master" -> "main")
NOTE: This is not a "Swift Playground" (app), this is a standalone, Xcode-playground.
I have have several existing playgrounds that were created a while ago, you know the story. They live on the "master" branch (they are hosted on bitbucket, but that probably doesn't matter here).
Last week, I went thru the process of removing all the "master" branches in my bitbucket repositories.
Afterwards, the filenames appear in the sidebar of Xcode, but tapping on the file displayed a blank window, no code.
I started down the usual troubleshooting in Xcode:

open file in finder, to confirm file is still there...
close; open the playground
quit; re-laounch Xcode
(even) reboot system

(I googled and didn't see anything obvious, so now I'm working down low-probability causes...)

I think the problem is caused when Xcode is running and the playground file's branch changed in local git repository.
I solved the problem by removing the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file.
rm ./playground.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/test.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
